# Uncertainty analysis using Bayesian bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, uncertainty

I am trying to use Bayesian bootstrap to asses uncertainty in a model, but I'm having difficulty to conclude my analysis.

I am independently training many randomly initialized instances of the model on different random subsets of the same dataset. In Bootstrap, we randomly sample data from the original dataset $X$ with replacement. While using the traditional method for sampling, the original data are equally weighted. In the Bayesian method, however, we are imposing a non-informative Dirichlet prior on the weights and sample points from the original dataset based on weights sampled from prior.

Given each sampled dataset $X_K$, I train my model and get a MAP estimate for model parameter $\theta_K$. Then, given an input test data, I evaluate the sample variance of the outputs from all deterministic models.

My questions are twofold:

1. If the original data has a dimension of $N$ and the sampled data is of dimension $K$, what is the relation between $K$ and $N$? I have read different instructions on different resources.
2. Do I apply any weights on model outputs of each model with parameter $\theta_K$ in the Bayesian model?